# Polymorphism in java resolving Parent class and Child class objects

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

I want to understand this:

```
ParentClass p=new ChildClass(); 
//Here ChildClass extends ParentClass
```

Is `p` object of `ParentClass` or of `ChildClass`?

Comment: P is ChildClass Object.

Comment: That is called Polymorphism  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar This is called Inheritance , not polymorphism

Comment: @M.S. Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms. Good luck with your OOP studies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is p object of ParentClass or of ChildClass?

`p` is an instance of `ChildClass`.  Any instance of `ChildClass` is also an instance of `ParentClass`.  The other way around is not true.

**EDIT:**

If you were to call `p.getClass()`, that will return `ChildClass`.

Comment: What is difference between 
`ParentClass p=new ChildClass();`
and
`ChildClass p=new ChildClass();`

Comment: @MS: If you declare the type to be `ChildClass`, then you will have access to members of `ChildClass` that are not available in `ParentClass`.

Comment: There is no difference as far as what object gets allocated on the heap.  The same object with the same behaviors and attributes is created in both cases.  The difference has to do with what you can do with the reference.  For example, if a method accepts an argument of type `ParentClass` you could pass a reference of type `ParentClass` or `ChildClass` to that method.  If the method accepts an argument of type `ChildClass` you could not pass a reference of type `ParentClass` to that method. Also if you define a method in `ChildClass`, you cannot invoke that method on a `ParnetClass` reference.

Comment: As an example, `StringBuffer o = new StringBuffer(); o.append("Hello");` is valid and will compile.  `Object o = new StringBuffer(); o.append("Hello");` will not compile because the reference type is `Object` and there is no `append` method in the `Object` class.  In both cases the same `StringBuffer` object is allocated on the heap.  The reference type limits how you can interact with that object.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Think about `p` as a view on the given object. You can view a `Dog` as an `Animal` (in which case you can e.g `feed()` it), or you can view it as a `Dog` (so you can get it to `bark()`). In other words, the variable's type that references an object will restrict what you can call on it, but does not change the type of the object.

Comment: What is difference between  `ParentClass p=new ChildClass();` and `ChildClass p=new ChildClass();`

Comment: The difference is what you can call on `p`. In the first case the compiler will fail if you try to call a method that only exists on the `ChildClass`, while in the second case it will not.

Answer (score 0):

p is an instance of `ChildClass` which of type `ParentClass` and 
using p you can call all the methods of ParentClass but you cannot call any method of  ChildClass.
Example

```
public class ParentClass{
public Person(){}
public void p(){
System.out.println("from p()");
}
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
public void c(){
System.out.println("from c()");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
ParentClass p = new ChildClass();
ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
p.p(); //possible
p.c(); //not possible
c.c();  //possible
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

`p` is not instance at all. it is just reference of type `ParentClass` that is pointing to object of `ChildClass` on heap memory.

`Objects` live on heap while references can be on stack memory or in other objects on heap. think `reference` as pointers in c/c++ with some additional functionality.

Your example is of inheritance where reference of type `ParentClass` can point to `ChildClass` object.

Comment: it's correct to call it instance as well i guess since we know it's a reference to an object in the Heap .

Comment: @Betlista - didn't understand your comment. what is 'common'? and references are not just pointers. they are more than that

Comment: Sorry, had to be "come on", can you describe better why `ParentClass p=new ChildClass();` is a reference and `ChildClass c=new ChildClass();` is not? What you meant by "more than that"?

Comment: @Betlista - Question was `Is p object of ParentClass or of ChildClass?`. variable `p` and `c` that you mentioned in you comment are both references to actual objects on heap. and both will point to object of type `ChildClass` Only difference will be methods they can call on that object. Being reference of type `ParentClass`, p will not be able to call methods of `ChildClass` object that is not known to it. and there where is differes from simple c / c++ pointers.

Comment: See [Java references and C pointers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer) for more explanation on this

Comment: "p is not instance at all. it is just reference of type ParentClass that is pointing to object of ChildClass on heap memory." - The original question makes clear that the asker is new to OO and the distinction you are drawing there is not going to prove helpful.  The difference between "is p an instance of ParentClass" and "is the object that the reference p is associated with an instance of ParentClass" is not one that is meaningful in this context.  It only works to further complicate the question.

Answer (score -2):

P is a reference in the stack of type ParentClass pointing to a childClass instance in the heap ,this enables you to just call class members defined in ParentClass and take advantage of Polymorphism on runtime through method overriding.